# sql previous week total

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking for a query to total previous week

**Current day**

```
SELECT Sum(total_cost)AS "total" 
FROM   purchases 
WHERE  datetime >= Curdate();
```

**Current Week**

```
SELECT SUM(total_cost)as "total" 
FROM purchases 
WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK);
```

**Previous day**

```
SELECT SUM(total_cost)AS "total"
FROM purchases
WHERE datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND datetime <= CURDATE();
```

Looking for query similar to this for calculating previous week. Can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want this:-

```
SELECT SUM(total_cost)AS "total"
    FROM purchases
`datetime ` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
AND `datetime ` < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: this gives me same result as current week

Comment: It is giving the result of the last 7 days. So if say today is 26-Sept-2013 then this will give the data for 19-Sept-2013 to 25-Sept-2013. And  thats what is previous week. Am I missing the obvious??

Comment: Im trying to get the total of the 7 days starting before the "current week"

Comment: @user1715025:- You are welcome. You can upvote my answer as well as that would help me improve my reputation!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select SELECT SUM(total_cost) AS "total"
  FROM purchases
  WHERE datetime between dateadd(d,-14,CURDATE()) and dateadd(d,-7,CURDATE())
```